# Automate script to run linear regression R

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am looking to run Linear Regression on the below data frame.

```
test<-data.frame(abc=c(2.4,3.2,8.9,9.8,10.0,3.2,5.4),
             city1_0=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5),
             city1_1=c(2.3,5.6,3,2.4,3.6,2.4,6.5),
             city1_2=c(4.2,1.4,2.6,2,6,3.6,2.4),
             city1_3=c(2.4,2.6,9.4,4.6,2.5,1.2,7.5),
             city1_4=c(8.2,4.2,7.6,3.4,1.7,5.2,9.7),
             city2_0=c(4.3,8.6,6,3.7,7.8,4.7,5.8),                               city2_1=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5))
```

Dataframe "test" is sample of the data. But original data frame contains 100 columns. I want to create a script for predicting values using linear regression. In this case, I want to build many models with different input variables.

For example, in the given dataframe, **abc** is the y variable. I want to build one model 
city1_1,city1_2,city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0, city2_0). Then other model with city1_2,city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0,city1_1,city2_0,city2_1)
and then 3rd model with input variable city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0,city1_1,city1_2,city2_0,city2_1), and so on.

These all variables are input to the Linear Regression.

This I have to do for 40 dataframes. O/P variable name remains same for every dataframe.

Comment: Try this, stepwise regression. If I am understanding what you want, this answer should get you there! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214682/stepwise-regression-in-r-how-does-it-work

Comment: @sconfluentus, Could you tell me how to run Stepwise Regression on more than 100 columns?

Comment: this package will get you started. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/leaps.pdf . It helps you select the "best" model. Any way you look at it, it will take a LONG time to run all the possible combinations on 100 colums, particularly if you have a lot of observations as well. test on a SMALL subset of rows to see that you have the models set up right first. But you should definitely try building this yourself..read the documents so that you can explain what you have done with some authority.